# How to upload large audio file to a django server given a blob url?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django, file

I've got a javascript that records audio using `MediaRecorder` and pushes the binary data into an array `chunk`. Once the user finishes recording, the data is converted into a `blob` and loaded to an HTML's `audio` element for playback. My issue is now trying to load this data onto the Django server at the same time. Most sample upload script I've seen has users manually loading an audio file into a form's `input` element and manually hitting a submit button, but my data is already loaded into a blob file so I am not sure how to proceed.

HTML

```
<div id="buttons">
    <form>
        <button id="record_btn" style="">Record</button>
        <input id="stop_btn" type="submit" value="Stop" disabled>
        <audio id="audio" controls>
            <source id="source" src="" type="audio/ogg"/>
        </audio>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var record = document.querySelector('#record_btn');   
var stop = document.querySelector('#stop_btn');

  if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
     console.log('getUserMedia supported.');
     navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia (
        // constraints - only audio needed for this app
        {
           audio: true
        })

        // Success callback
        .then(function(stream) {
          var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
          record.onclick = function() {
            mediaRecorder.start();
            record.disabled = true;
            stop.disabled = false;
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
            console.log("recorder started");
            record.style.background = "red";
            record.style.color = "black";
          }

          var chunks = [];

          mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            chunks.push(e.data);
          }
          stop.onclick = function() {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            record.disabled = false;
            stop.disabled = true;
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
            console.log("recorder stopped");
            record.style.background = "";
            record.style.color = "";
          }

          mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
            console.log("recorder stopped");
            var audio = document.querySelector('#audio');
            var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
            chunks = [];
            var audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            $("#source").attr("src", audioURL);
            $("#audio")[0].load();
            stream.getTracks()[0].stop();

            //CODE TO UPLOAD BLOB DATA TO DJANGO SERVER
            ????????? 
            //
          }
        })

        // Error callback
        .catch(function(err) {
           console.log('The following getUserMedia error occured: ' + err);
        }
     );   } else {
     console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');   }
```

Would the current setup work well for an hour-long recording? If there are any better way of recording audio on the client side and uploading it to server I would greatly appreciate any guidence.

Comment: I mean, if you were using the Django Rest Framework you could just attach the data to a post and catch it on the back-end with a specific URL end-point.  Raw Django you can probably create a URL on its own and set up your form to auto-post.  I don't know enough about the Djang forms system to know if you can embed one that submits based upon a JS call and then loads a response.

Comment: This may help: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**JQuery Ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send blob data to Django server

```
var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });

console.log("start sending binary data...");
var form = new FormData();
form.append('audio', blob);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/<your api endpoint>/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('response' + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function () {
       // handle error case here
    }
});
```

And in Django view, you can easily retrieve blob using

```
audio_data = request.FILES['audio']
# you can directly assign audio_data to FileField model attribute
```

> **Note:** Above code will work fine if the data is not that large, which exceeds your server timeout

---

If the file is really large then I will recommend you to upload your file using [tus protocol](https://tus.io/protocols/resumable-upload.html)

This approach offers you to upload a large file in chunks. For the Django project, you can use [django-tus](https://github.com/alican/django-tus) package.